# Unable to edit a word template 2007 using Microsoft.Office.Interop when running through ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am unable to edit a word template 2007 when I am trying to run my web application through IIS using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word .But in development environment it is running fine.
Below is my code sample,

```
            using Word = Microsoft.Office;

            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            Object oTrue = true;
            Object oFalse = false;
            //Start Word and create a new document.
            Word.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Word.Interop.Word.Application();
            Word.Interop.Word.Document oDoc;
            oWord.Visible = true;

            //Using Template format of the existing Word Doc
            object oTemplate = "C:\\MyTemplate.dotx";
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            //Get the Bookmark location from Template Document 
            Word.Interop.Word.Table wTbl = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item("Test").Range.Tables[1];
```

while runing through IIS oDoc is coming as null and I checked the `oWord` object it is coming as `System._Comobject`.But incase development environment oWord object is coming as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and working perfectly.

Comment: Do you have Office Word installed on the *server*?

Comment: Runing Office application on server is not very good idea - not only it is not supported by Microsoft, but it also may not work at all/hang server code (i.e. by showing dialogs)...

Comment: yes I have office word installed in the system.Currently I am trying to host the application in my local system only..